# Jenkins: wrong charset on Build Time Graph rendering

Tags: jenkins

We recently moved our Jenkins from a CentOS 6 Server to a CentOS 7 LXC Container. Since that, the rendering of graphs is broken. It affects the Build Time Trend graph as well as the Test Result Trend graph.

[image: Test Result Trend]

I checked the environment of master and slave - both running with `LANG=en_US.utf8`.

I'm not sure how this graphs are rendered and how the rendering is influenced by OS level changes.
Can someone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I would  prefer to comment, as this is mostly clarify questions, but I do not have enough reputation).

Questions/comments:

- Did you keep same version of JDK (i.e. OpenJDK vs Oracle JDK).
  Why: They seem to behave differently with respects to fonts.
- Did you install any fonts in the LXC container, and more specifically, the fontsconfig package?
  Why: Based on my local Jenkins, I see the image in question is actually a png file, complete with graph and text. I.e. the Java process is generating an image, using local fonts to render. This is not fancy HTML, using fonts within your browser.

I have seen similar issues when switching from Oracle JDK to OpenJDK, missing fontconfig and required fonts locally. However, each time I have always seen telltale exceptions/stack traces in the log file(s).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem disappeared. But I'm not sure why. ':) Probably the fontconfig and png-libs fixed it, which I installed with graphviz lately.